# Redux error: mapDispatchToProps throws error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to react-redux and I am having some difficulty in understanding the syntax. I am pasting my sample code below... please help me understand if there are any syntactical errors.

**SampleParent.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchNames, fetchDownloadLink } from '../../actions/actions'
import SampleChild from '../ui/SampleChild'

class SampleParent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props) ;
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchNames());
}

render() {
    return(<div><ul id="myUL">{this.props.reports.map((report) => (
                    <li>
                        <SampleChild
                            key={report.id}
                            label={report.label}
                            uri={() => fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+this.props.uri+".pdf")}
                        />
                    </li>))}</ul></div>)}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
const { reports } = state
return {
    reports
}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    fetchDownloadLink(url) {
        dispatch(
            fetchDownloadLink(url)
        )
    }
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReportsApp)
```

**SampleChild.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchDownloadLink } from '../../actions/actions'
class OpenReport extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props) ;
}

render(){
    return(<div className="in_sample" id={this.props.label}>
                {this.props.label}
                <a href={this.props.uri}>
                    <img src="../images/pdf-file_128.png" height="25px" width="25px"></img></a><br></br></div>
    )
}
}
module.exports = OpenReport;
```

Currently I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function
at ReportsApp.componentDidMount (bundle.js:39883)
```

Basically what I need to do is get a url as a string from the 'fetchDownloadLink ' function and pass this string to my child component. Is there any other way to do that?

Please suggest... 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to the **[Documentaion](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)**:

> mapDispatchToProps returns an object that somehow uses dispatch to bind
>   action creators in your own way.

However in your case you are returning an object without keys. Change your function to

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {

    return {
        fetchDownloadLink: (url) => dispatch(fetchDownloadLink(url))
        }
    }

}
```

MoreOver, using `connect` function you need to connect `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` function to the component in which you will be using the action creators which in your case is `SampleParent`

Also if you pass `mapDispatchToProps` as the second parameter to `connect`, then `dispatch` is not available as a prop to your component.

So change your code to the following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchNames, fetchDownloadLink } from '../../actions/actions'
import SampleChild from '../ui/SampleChild'

class SampleParent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props) ;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch } = this.props
        this.props.fetchNames();
    }

    render() {
        return(<div><ul id="myUL">{this.props.reports.map((report) => (
                        <li>
                            <SampleChild
                                key={report.id}
                                label={report.label}
                                uri={() => this.props.fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+this.props.uri+".pdf")}
                            />
                        </li>))}</ul></div>)}
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {

    const { reports } = state
    return {
        reports
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {

    return {
        fetchDownloadLink: (url) => dispatch(fetchDownloadLink(url)),
        fetchNames: () => dispatch(fetchNames)
        }
    }

}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SampleParent)
```

Comment: Hello Shubham, Thank you for the help, but when I run this, 'uri={() => this.props.fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+this.props.uri+".pdf")', it is passing the entire function as a parameter to the SampleChild component. Can it not be done that this function returns the URL string here instead and passes only the URL formed ahead...? instead of passing the function by itself... as the function is not accessible in SampleChild... or how to make it accessible to SampleChild?

Comment: Yes it is possible,  if you write `uri={this.props.fetchDownloadLink("localhost:8080/…;)}`

Comment: That somhow stopped displaying even the other elements inside the <li> tags :( Or instead of using dispatch is there any other way to invoke the function?

Comment: Do you want to update the redux state with this function, if yes then you have to use dispatch, else you can use it even without that. Also were you getting any error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing your action creator as a prop `uri` to your child component, and then using that prop as an HREF tag.

You should instead pass it as `onChildClick` (example name) prop to your report item component, and call it on the `onClick` prop of the `<a>`.

`<a onClick={ this.props.onChildClick }>xxxx</a>`

The previous answer about the action creator mapping is fine, but you don't even need a function: if you use an object with functions as keys, they will be wrapped with `dispatch` for you.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchDownloadLink
}
```

**EDIT after your updated question**
I see the problem now. You don't have `dispatch` as prop because you're using `mapDispatchToProps` to provide some action creators as props. It doesn't make sense to map dispatch to `fetchDownloadLink` and not doing it as well for `fetchNames`. Map both or neither, but you shouldn't mix and match.

Comment: Iam sorry, I dnt exactly understand what you mean by passing it as a 'onChildClick (example name)' prop... how exactly do you refer to invoke the 'fetchDownloadLink' function?

Comment: just clarifying... 'fetchDownloadLink(url)' is returning a formed url as a string, that url needs to be hit on in the child component